# Entity Framework Code First invalid column name Company_CompanyID

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm making my first foray into Code First. Most of my tables are working ok, but I'm getting an 'invalid column name Company_CompanyID' when querying a table named Bids.

When I reverse engineer my database for a little sample application, I don't get this error. I've compared the Bid class and mapping from the sample application to my real application, and I can't find a difference. The SQL generated for the Bids query in my actual application looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[LockCount] AS [LockCount], 
    [Extent1].[BidID] AS [BidID], 
    [Extent1].[LocaleID] AS [LocaleID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[FileLocation] AS [FileLocation], 
    [Extent1].[EstimatorContactID] AS [EstimatorContactID], 
    [Extent1].[OwnerContactID] AS [OwnerContactID], 
    [Extent1].[OwnerContactContactID] AS [OwnerContactContactID], 
    [Extent1].[GCContactID] AS [GCContactID], 
    [Extent1].[GCContactContactID] AS [GCContactContactID], 
    [Extent1].[ArchitectContactID] AS [ArchitectContactID], 
    [Extent1].[ArchitectContactContactID] AS [ArchitectContactContactID], 
    [Extent1].[BuilderContactID] AS [BuilderContactID], 
    [Extent1].[BuilderContactContactID] AS [BuilderContactContactID], 
    [Extent1].[DrawingNumber] AS [DrawingNumber], 
    [Extent1].[BidDate] AS [BidDate], 
    [Extent1].[PlanDate] AS [PlanDate], 
    [Extent1].[RevisionDate] AS [RevisionDate], 
    [Extent1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    [Extent1].[FinishDate] AS [FinishDate], 
    [Extent1].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
    [Extent1].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
    [Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Extent1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Extent1].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
    [Extent1].[J1] AS [J1], 
    [Extent1].[J2] AS [J2], 
    [Extent1].[J3] AS [J3], 
    [Extent1].[J4] AS [J4], 
    [Extent1].[J5] AS [J5], 
    [Extent1].[J6] AS [J6], 
    [Extent1].[J7] AS [J7], 
    [Extent1].[J8] AS [J8], 
    [Extent1].[PriceIndex] AS [PriceIndex], 
    [Extent1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
    [Extent1].[Proposal] AS [Proposal], 
    [Extent1].[JobOptions] AS [JobOptions], 
    [Extent1].[LastEstimatedDate] AS [LastEstimatedDate], 
    [Extent1].[IsTemplate] AS [IsTemplate], 
    [Extent1].[Awarded] AS [Awarded], 
    [Extent1].[JobStatus] AS [JobStatus], 
    [Extent1].[LockedByUserID] AS [LockedByUserID], 
    [Extent1].[LockedDate] AS [LockedDate], 
    [Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    [Extent1].[Company_CompanyID] AS [Company_CompanyID]
    FROM [dbo].[Bids] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (([Extent1].[LockedByUserID] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[LockedByUserID] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent1].[LockedByUserID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

All of the columns in my Bids table are represented in the query, plus the additional `Company_CompanyID`. I'm not sure how to go about trying to figure out what's being mapped to `Company_CompanyID`. Could someone please provide some pointers on how I can go about figuring out what's causing that `Company_CompanyID` to come in? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Foreign Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) column, which is used to link row in Bids table with row in Companies table. By default Entity Framework uses following pattern for Foreign Key names generation:

```
{navigationPropertyName}_{primaryKeyPropertyNameOfReferencedEntity}
```

I.e. if you have company entity:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And bid which has navigation property for company:

```
public class Bid
{
    public int BidID { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then generated foreign key filed name for employee table will look like

```
Company_CompanyID
```